# Sweave syntax highlighting for Sublime Text

Tags: sweave, sublimetext2

Currently Sublime Text 2 with installed `LaTeXTools` bundle stumbles over Sweave/knitr code blocks. How can I tell ST to either ignore everything of the form

```
<<arguments here>>=

@
```

or, even better, to treat it as R source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's now the [SublimeKnitr](https://github.com/andrewheiss/SublimeKnitr) bundle that's made specifically made for Sublime Text. Install from GitHub source or via Package Control.

Answer (score 3):

The Sweave Textmate bundle (or at least the essential parts) will also work with Sublime Text 2. Just download the bundle from https://github.com/textmate/sweave.tmbundle and move it to the `Packages` directory.